# Numerically solving a BVP for a 2nd order ODE with mixed Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions with the finite difference method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I would like to solve a simple BVP for a second order differential equation on the domain $I=[0,\pi/2]$ using the finite difference method.
$$
u''(x)+u(x)=0\\
u(0)=0\\
u'(\pi/2)=0
$$
By construction, $u(x) = c \sin(x)$ is a solution for any $c$. To use the finite difference method, we construct an $n\times n$ matrix of the form
$$
A = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\begin{bmatrix}
-2&1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&-2&1&0&\cdots&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
0&\cdots&0&1&-2&1\\
0&\cdots&0&0&2&-2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here in the first row we are assuming $u_0=0$ for the zero Dirichlet condition, and we are assuming $u_n=u_{n+1}$ so that $u'(x_n)=0$. Then we solve the discretized differential equation, which becomes a linear system,
$$
A\vec{u}+\vec{u}=0\\
(A+I)\vec{u}=0,
$$
but since $(A+I)$ is invertible, the only solution to this equation is $\vec{u}=0$. How can I recover the non-trivial solutions?

Comment: Side note: you can achieve higher accuracy using a "ghost point" method; as is, your estimate for the ODE is second order while your estimate for the Neumann BC is first order, and this results in only first order accuracy overall. You can instead introduce a point $u_{n+1}$ outside the domain and impose $u_{n+1}=u_{n-1}$ along with the ODE at $i=n$.

Comment: Anyway, the idea is that the number $\pi/2$ is actually part of the solution. Specifically, you want to set up your coefficient matrix for the whole problem with $\Delta x$ thought of as a variable, then solve for $\Delta x$ such that the coefficient matrix is singular. Then $n\Delta x$ will be an approximation of $\pi/2$ given to you as part of your numeric solution.

Comment: I edited the Neumann BC discretization to be 2nd order like you recommended. Your other comment is a bit confusing. Let's say we rescale the problem to be on the interval $[0,1]$, so the BVP becomes $u''(x)+\tfrac{\pi^2}{4}u(x)=0$, $u(0)=0$, $u'(1)=0$. Then you're saying that there is an infinite collection of pairs $(n,\Delta x)$ so that $n\Delta x$ goes to 1 and $A+\tfrac{\pi^2}{4}I$ is a singular matrix?

Comment: You have to allow slack in either the size of the domain or the eigenvalue. It doesn't really matter which. If you allow slack in the size of the domain, then your eigenvalue can be exactly $-1$ (i.e. you can search for $\Delta x$ such that $A(\Delta x)+I$ is singular and the domain is of size $n\Delta x$). Then the domain size, $n \Delta x$, will tend to $\pi/2$. If you allow slack in the eigenvalue, then your domain size can be exactly $\pi/2$ (i.e. you search for $\lambda$ such that $A((\pi/2)/n)-\lambda I$ is singular). Then the eigenvalue, $\lambda$, will tend to $-1$.

Comment: (Cont.) Rescaling like that doesn't get rid of this issue about slack, it more or less just interchanges the role of the domain size and the eigenvalue.

Comment: Some Matlab/Octave code: n=1e2; h=1/n; e=ones(n,1); V=[e -2*e e]; A=spdiags(V,[-1 0 1],n,n)/h^2; A(n,n-1)=-A(n,n); [E,L]=eig(A); [m,i]=min(abs(diag(L)+pi^2/4)); plot(h*pi/2*(1:n),E(:,i)). You can swap out 1e2 for whatever other number of points you like. You'll see here that L(i,i), the approximate eigenvalue, is m, about 5e-5, away from $-\pi^2/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the number $\pi/2$, that is to say the domain size in which these boundary conditions result in an eigenvalue of $-1$, is part of the solution of the problem. It will come with its own numerical error. This formulation means you are asked to find $L$ such that $u''+u=0,u(0)=0,u'(L)=0$ has a nontrivial solution. This $L$ is $n\Delta x$, so you want $A+I$ to be singular, or equivalently you want $\Delta x^2 A + \Delta x^2 I$ to be singular. So you want $\Delta x$ to be $\sqrt{-\lambda}$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix $\Delta x^2 A$ (which depends only on $n$ and not on $\Delta x$).

If you don't like the idea of the domain size as a variable, then you can hold the domain size fixed at $\pi/2$ and allow for the numerical eigenvalue to differ from $-1$ instead.

Either way as you observed you need to leave some slack, because if the domain is size $\pi/2$ then the eigenvalue you get is never exactly $-1$, and conversely if you set the eigenvalue to be exactly $-1$ then the domain size you get is not exactly $\pi/2$.